# AngularJs: how to do ng-repeat over multiple variables like ng-init can do?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With ng-init you can use multiple vars:

```
ng-init="var1=value1; var2=value2"
```

I tried something similar with ng-repeat but it doesn't work

```
ng-repeat= "var1 in var1s; var2 in var2s"
```

Is there a way to do so with a correct syntax ?

Update: I want to use var1 for header and var2 for content of an accordion http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion

Comment: You can only use ng-repeat to loop one variable. 
           `code`ng-repeat = "var1 in var1s"

Comment: what is your expected output? to be able to access both vars in the repeater? have the items alternate? to repeat one list then the other list?

Comment: I wonder what behaviour are you expecting with multiple vars in ng-repeat? Should var1 be repeated, or var2 or something like cartesian product of var1s and var2s?

Comment: @JibinMathews My guess is that `var1s` and `var2s` are expected to be the same length, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen then your answer is the solution.

Comment: Update: I want to use var1 for header and var2 for content of an accordion http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, `ng-repeat` only works over a single variable.  But one workaround would be to use `ng-repeat` over a single *object* which has two keys, one for each variable you want to access.  The view might look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataObject">
    {{data.var1}} {{data.var2}}
</div>
```

In your controller, the scoped variable `dataObject` would have two (or more) keys, one called `var1` and the other `var2`.

Comment: Update: I want to use var1 for header and var2 for content of an accordion http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion

Comment: I'm not sure this would change my general answer...or that this changes your question.

Comment: @tim-biegleisen yes thanks I did just precise for everybody. Not sure which one is best answer I pick the other because there is sample code I can try but I'll try yours too.

Comment: Me likey because: Your controller is where any non-trivial data logic should happen; not your view.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, There is no way you can use two ng repeats variable with a semi colon separation like ng-init.

**ng-repeat** only works with single variable which is an array. If you want to have ng repeat for two different arrays, you could use **`nested-ng-repeat`**.

Otherwise merge your two arrays as one using **`key,value`**. Then you will be able to do ng-repeat over key,value and access them.

**[`DEMO USING NESTED NG-REPEAT`](https://embed.plnkr.co/xLHJqwGpBYBB81onpQBO/)**

Comment: Update: I want to use var1 for header and var2 for content of an accordion http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion

Comment: @user310291 here is a sample https://embed.plnkr.co/xLHJqwGpBYBB81onpQBO/

Comment: If `var1s` and `var2s`  both have same length, then try using one by `$index`.

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks for the sample should suit my need

Comment: why did you remove the answer